# Java insert node into XML (.RDG) file using Java DOM

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am currently trying to write a java app that will automatically insert new nodes into my .RDG file that my remote desktop connection manager uses. Basically, I have a bunch of new servers I would like to add automatically and I want to make a java program to do it for me. However, I am stuck at a particular part of the code. My .RDG file has the following format for the servers in the .rdg file:

```
             <server>
                <name>www.testsite.com</name>
                <displayName>test</displayName>
                <comment />
                <logonCredentials inherit="FromParent" />
                <connectionSettings inherit="FromParent" />
                <gatewaySettings inherit="FromParent" />
                <remoteDesktop inherit="FromParent" />
                <localResources inherit="FromParent" />
                <securitySettings inherit="FromParent" />
                <displaySettings inherit="FromParent" />
            </server>
```

My code to insert a new server node is as follows so far:

```
public void insertNewServer(){
        try{
            Document document = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(pathToRDGFile));
            Node productionServersNode = document.getElementsByTagName("group").item(2);

            Element newServer = document.createElement("server");
            Element newServerName = document.createElement("name");
            newServerName.appendChild(document.createTextNode("server100.servers.com"));
            Element newServerDisplayName = document.createElement("displayName");
            newServerDisplayName.appendChild(document.createTextNode("TS100"));

        }
```

I am stuck as how to handle the next few elements in the file. I know how to insert text nodes, but the next few nodes are nodes like:

```
                <logonCredentials inherit="FromParent" />
                <connectionSettings inherit="FromParent" />
                <gatewaySettings inherit="FromParent" />
                <remoteDesktop inherit="FromParent" />
                <localResources inherit="FromParent" />
                <securitySettings inherit="FromParent" />
                <displaySettings inherit="FromParent" />
```

And currently from the tutorials I've read I can't seem to find which particular method is best to use for inserting nodes that contain all of the information that they need in the same set of brackets. I would know how to set it if, for example, it were:

```
<logonCredentials> logon creds </logonCredentials>
```

but I am stuck as to what java method to use when I want to insert a node such as:

```
<logonCredentials inherit="FromParent" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get started from a tutorial, it's usually a good idea to reference the API documentation for additional information.

http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html

http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Element.html

```
Element logonCredentials = document.createElement("logonCredentials");
logonCredentials.setAttribute("inherit", "FromParent");
newServer.appendChild(logonCredentials);
```